# Compare array of quiz answers (A/B/C/D) to criteria combinations

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm building a relatively simple quiz, have all the markup and form logic built out, now on submit I am getting an array of answers (A/B/C/D) that I need to compare to various combinations from a list of criteria

Here is what the criteria looks like. Too add to the complexity I'm trying to set it up to allow various answers, denoted by a `/` separator in the string. Below is a simplified representation of the code, assume that I am working within the form submit handler, and `results` is the form data I get back from groups of radio inputs.

```
var criteria = [
  {
    combination: ['B', 'B', 'A/B', 'C', 'A/B/C/D'],
    type: 'Type A'
  },
  {
    combination: ['B', 'A/B/C/D', 'A/B', 'A/B/D', 'A/B/C/D'],
    type: 'Type B'
  },
  {
    combination: ['D', 'A', 'C', 'A/B', 'A/B/C/D'],
    type: 'Type C'
  }
]

// this data comes back from form
var results = ['B', 'A', 'A', 'D', 'C'];



function compareResults(results, criteria) {

  $.each( results, function (i, answer) {

    // ?

  })
}


compareResults(results, criteria)
```

I'm having a brainfart on how to step through and compare to the multidimensional object/array. I know I need a `for .. in` loop, to `.split('/')`, etc. Any help is appreciated.

**Edit**

If it makes it easier, I can structure the criteria combinations like so:

```
combination: {
  '1' : ['B'], 
  '2' : ['B'], 
  '3' : ['A','B'], 
  '4' : ['C'], 
  '5' : ['A','B','C','D'], 
},
```

Comment: Could you explain a little more what's going on here? Is `results` an array of answers to different questions? What does `criteria` represent?

Comment: shouldn't be hard, but need some additional detail. How does the Type A,B,C come into play? Do you compare with each, with just one, etc? Is an acceptable answer "AND" or "OR"? That is, if the criteria is A/B/C, will "A" be true or does it need to be all three? If the later, do they need to be in order. You might get better help by simplifying your question to something more basic that can easily be consumed, then add complexity from there.

Comment: @AutumnLeonard I tried to explain right before the block of code. The `/` denotes a separator, as the results could return a different answer and still be 'eligible' for the criteria. If you look at my edit I think i structured the criteria a little more clearly albeit more verbose. So in this case `results` would qualify for 'Type B'.

Comment: @SteveJ the 'Type A, B' etc can you be whatever you want it to be, it's what the user is receiving as their ultimate result to the quiz. Perhaps I complicated things by misnaming variables, but 'results' in this case is what i'm getting back from the form handler. The code I posted is a simplified representation. I'll make clarity edits.

Comment: @SteveJ forgot to answer, the logic is `OR` (working with radio inputs vs checkbox)

Comment: If you can only have one answer (radio)...what are all the combinations supposed to be? Seems over complicated

Comment: @charlietfl I think you're getting confused by the language or naming, it is a combination in the sense that one result could accept multiple answer values for a given question. consider a scenario where q#1 is an age range question, q#2 is a salary question, but the result is the same if the answer to q#2 is A or B, but not if q#1 answer is different. also - analytics.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you wanted. I'm assuming the result can only be one (i.e criteria are mutually exclusive, or their intersection is empty).

```
function compareResults(results, criteria) {
  for(var z = 0; z < criteria.length; z++){
      var cr = criteria[z];
      var matches = true;
      for(var k = 0; k < results.length; k++){
          var combinationItems = cr.combination[k].split("/"),
             item = results[k],
             itemMatches = false;

          for(var i = 0; i < combinationItems.length; i++){
              if(combinationItems[i] == item){
                itemMatches = true;
                break;
              }
          }

          if(!itemMatches){
              matches = false;
              break;
          }
      }

      if(matches) return cr.type;
  }

  return null;
}
```

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you! Does my edit to the formatting of `combination` make this easier?

Comment: @elzi it might make it more readable, but it's pretty similar implementation wise. It could also be done using a 2d array for the criteria, instead of the string number indexes